# How to access a field from linked table in dropdown list

Tags: yii2

I have linked tables and when I create dropdown list like this

```
<?=  $form->field($model, 'player_id')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(Player::find()->all(), 'id', 'category_id'),
            ['prompt' => 'Select'])
?>
```

it works. 
I need to have in my list category name and not category id (the table `category` consists of `id` and `name` and `category_id` from my current table is linked to `category.id`)
How can I make that?

Comment: Do you have that relationship in your models?

Comment: Yes and I can use it in GridView (name instead of id). I don't know how to make that in dropdown list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your relationship is called `getCategory`, you just add the corresponding `joinWith` and use the `name` attribute:

```
$form->field($model, 'player_id')->dropDownList(
    ArrayHelper::map(Player::find()->joinWith('category')->all(), 'id', 'name'),
    ['prompt' => 'Select'])
```

**Update with your request:** Your `getNameAndLastname` should include your category data:

```
public function getNameAndLastname() {
  $cat = $this->getCategory()->one();
  return $this->lastname.' '.$this->firstname.' - Cat: '.$cat->name; 
}
```

And now:

```
$form->field($model, 'player_id')->dropDownList(
    ArrayHelper::map(Player::find()->joinWith('category')->all(), 'id', 'nameAndLastname'),
    ['prompt' => 'Select'])
```

Comment: Thank you @gmc! It works.   I have one more question: how can I make concatenation of 2 or 3 fields in dropdown list: I need to make name, surname (both from one table) and right after category.name (from linked table `category`). Now I can make first and second but not both together :)

Comment: Create a method in your model that returns the concatenation of those fields (for example, `getFullName()`), and call that method when mapping:  `ArrayHelper::map(Player::find()->joinWith('category')->all(), 'id', 'fullName')`

Comment: I already have that method:     `public function getNameAndLastname() 
    {
        return $this->lastname.' '.$this->firstname;
    }`   but how to add category.name to there? Which is the right way to do it?

Comment: Thanks. I did exactly the same before . And always get  "PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object". Something is wrong but I don't know what it is :(

Comment: The same ErrorException.. Strange. I will keep trying to fix it.. Thanks for your help. I see that it should be ok but for some reason it is not.